# How to access button in next fragment after swipe?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

As you can see in this photo, if I click the 2 button in Title 1, the `Fragment` in `FrameLayout` appears. However, if I swipe to Title 2, the two buttons are not working.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
package com.flashcards;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link BaseFlashCardsFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class BaseFlashCardsFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private int position;
    private String mParam2;

    public BaseFlashCardsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param position Parameter 1.
     * @return A new instance of fragment BaseFlashCardsFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BaseFlashCardsFragment newInstance(int position) {
        BaseFlashCardsFragment fragment = new BaseFlashCardsFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION, 0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = null;
        int layoutId;
        switch (position) {
            case 0: layoutId = R.layout.limits_flashcardsfragment1; break;
            case 1: layoutId = R.layout.limits_flashcardsfragment2; break;
            default: layoutId = R.layout.limits_flashcardsfragment3; break;
        }

        rootView = inflater.inflate(layoutId, container, false);
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonterm).setOnClickListener(this);
        rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttondefinition).setOnClickListener(this);
        switchPage(new limits_fragmentpageA());
        switchPage(new limits_fragmentpageB());

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int viewId = view.getId();

        if (viewId == R.id.buttonterm)
            switchPage(new limits_fragmentpageA());
        else if (viewId == R.id.buttondefinition)
            switchPage(new limits_fragmentpageAA());
        else if (viewId == R.id.buttonterm)
            switchPage(new limits_fragmentpageB());
        else if (viewId == R.id.buttondefinition)
            switchPage(new limits_fragmentpageBB());

    }

    private void switchPage (Fragment fragment){
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.activity_main_fragmentcontainer, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

You can also [download the project](https://mega.nz/#!KVBnUBwT!qwnSq1i19XbxlfSyq7r0acz55ldiU9KMpKgFzfXA4YY) to get a clear view.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you need to have ALL elements (buttons, viewpager, title etc)  in your activity, not in fragment, because its are shared among all the fragments, so you do not need to recreate them in each fragment.

To change title (and lower hint), you need to add `OnPageChangeListener` to viewpager adapter.

To switch fragment between term/definition you need to pass the event directly in `OnClickListener` of those buttons, like "`(BaseCardFragment)adapter.instantiateItem(viewpager,viewpager.getCurrentItem).flipToTerm() or flipToDefinition()`"

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that if you are in fragment you should you `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`
Probably you should just rewrite `switchPage()` like this

`private void switchPage (Fragment fragment){
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.activity_main_fragmentcontainer, fragment)
                .commit();
 }`

Comment: The getChildFragmentManager(); is working, however it can only display one fragment and this line of code is not working "switchPage(new limits_fragmentpageB());"

I want it to switch to a new fragment.